# Implementing shortcut sorting like that of Google maps

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a project which consist of sorting by distance the nearby ATMs. Now I want to add the functionality which can let the user chose a particular affiliate Bank and just show it corresponding ATMs.

[image]

I want the bank names to appear as 'home' 'restaurants' 'gas' etc as on this Google map android app. I just want some ideas cause I don't know how to start.

Comment: Maybe start here? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview